# Mysql query in with the answer true, false

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I was not too long ago studying java, so maybe I have a stupid question.

I have a table, where i store some info. 
And i want to check in this table on availability of some information (it will be only one line), and if yes - take from this line, the information in a particular column, if no - do another thing.

I really don`t know how to do this.
My idea was something like this: at first - check the table:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE nickname = "kvant";
```

then if true, do another query with searching info.
and do this with condition if\else. but all my attempts not turn.

I hope for your help, sorry for my awry English.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What exactly are you trying to do? Please also add example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the data exists like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE nickname = "kvant")
BEGIN
    --value is found so go ahead 
END
ELSE
    --value not found
BEGIN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to query the database and get the result. `If result!=Null {//do something} else {//Do something}`

(Can use `try - catch` as well)

Answer (score 0):

Pure java possible solution:

Try to get that value in the query. Get the ResultSet rs of that query and:

```
if(rs.next()) {
    String value = rs.getString("value"); //Assuming the column is value and that it is a String.
    //Do whatever you want with the value
} else {
    //The other thing
}
```

If you can not take the value from the first ResultSet, do another query in the if.

Answer (score 0):

write in sql like `select case exists (select * from yourtable where condition) then 'dothis thing' else 'dootherthing' from 'yourtable' where 'yourcondition'`

since you wanted to run some other query after you know you have some conditon exists.

Comment: i`m trying to do smth like this - i got error.
`select case no exists (select * from test where name = "Kvant") then (insert into test values (null, "Sarvepalli"));`
but if i check it seperatly, like this `select * from test where name = "Kvant"` or this `insert into test values (null, "Sarvepalli")` - it`s work normally.